# connectTimeout in okhttp3 finish too fast

Tags: android, okhttp

I use `implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"` and this doesn't work as expected.

```
.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
.callTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
```

It's finish too fast ! This 4 and 10 seconds aren't respected. (from my point of view not working) Or how to explain that ?

For demonstration I made a repo with CI https://github.com/hannesa2/okHttpTest/pull/1/checks?check_run_id=1842237161

I run it on Emulator and try from Emulator to connect to a non-hosted server. My expectation is a timeout of 4 seconds

```
private var client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
        .writeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(7))
        .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(7))
        .callTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
        .build()

val request: Request = Request.Builder()
    .url(server) // non routable address
    .build()
catchThrowable { client.newCall(request).execute() }
```

### A: Local

Simply run `./gradlew test`
[image]

### B: CI

https://github.com/hannesa2/okHttpTest/pull/2/checks?check_run_id=1842293253

[image]

### Who can explain what's going on here ?

Why does a connect to Emulator hosted non-existing-server (for test purpose) the `.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4))` doesn't work ?

Comment: If it tries to connect to the local network and fails immediately then it should fail quickly.  Why are you expecting and why do you want it to take longer if there isn't a server there? Are you starting a server at that address?

Comment: How would you test a bad network, where some specific action should happen after x seconds ?

Comment: Look into mockwebserver and configure it to behave as you want in the test.